# How do I prevent my computer from going straight to Windows?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-7, installation, lenovo, boot-failure

I bought a Lenovo B570 laptop today, and one of the first things I did was burn an Oneiric LiveCD and install it. This was more trouble than I expected. It didn't automatically load to the CD when I restarted; it just booted Windows 7 like before. I had to press F12 at boot and use a very unintuitive menu to get to the LiveCD.

So now I've installed Ubuntu and restarted, but once again it's just booting to Windows like nothing happened instead of showing the familiar GRUB menu. What's going on here? (This is my first Windows 7 computer; my previous one had Vista dual-booted.)

**EDIT:** I should clarify that I can't load Ubuntu at *all*. Or at least I don't know how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a really similar computer to yours (the v570). I made a post in the forum detailing a fairly straight forward way to get the boot loader to work and finish the installation. Let me know if you have any more questions. Here is the link:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1863125

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks a bunch! (Only problem was that I had to install Boot-Repair from the command line, but their site had instructions, so _no problemo_.)

Answer (score 0):

Check the below link this will help to set default os ubuntu.    [GrubHowto
    ChangeDefaultOS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GrubHowto/ChangeDefaultOS)

Back Up Grub Settings

Copy this line into the terminal and press enter, it will back up your menu.lst and you can use the backup to restore your default settings.

sudo cp /boot/grub/menu.lst /boot/grub/menu.lst_backup

Open in a Text Editor

Edit the menu.lst file with one of the following commands (depending on what version of Ubuntu you're using):

Ubuntu

gksudo gedit /boot/grub/menu.lst

Kubuntu

kdesu kate /boot/grub/menu.lst

Xubuntu

gksudo mousepad /boot/grub/menu.lst

Finding the Line

```
Find this line in the document that was just opened, it will read like this:
```

### default num

## Set the default entry to the entry number NUM. Numbering starts from 0, and

## the entry number 0 is the default if the command is not used.

...
default     0
...

```
Replace the 0 with the number on the startup list corresponding to the option you want, counting from 0. For example, if you have a list like this one and want to change to Windows XP Home:
```

title      Ubuntu, kernel 2.6.15-27-amd64-generic
...
title      Ubuntu, memtest86+
...
title      Other operating systems:
...
title      Microsoft Windows XP Home

...you would change the number to 3. It is important to note that each lines such as "Other Operating Systems" should be counted as well.

```
Alternatively you can replace the number with the word 'saved' which will make the default whichever entry was last used. Each entry that should be remembered must have the 'savedefault' keyword, this is the case for the normal Ubuntu entries, but not the recovery alternatives. WARNING: If you are using dmraid do not change this entry to 'saved' or your array will desync and will not let you boot your system.
Save the edited file
```

Answer (score 0):

www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/windows-installer

Download Ubuntu straight from here, then install it and everytime you boot your computer it gives you the option to choose which one you use